# how to copy entire content of the trace window to text file in canoe

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

i would like to know is there any way to copy the trace window data to text file ??

I've tried to copy every thing by "ctrl + a" then tried to paste in a text file, but unfortunately it is copying only some part of data.

even though the logging option is exist in canoe, but it is not recorded in the test, right now the data is present in trace window. i would like to recover the data from trace window to text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click in the trace window, select `Import/Export` -> `Export...`, enter the file path and name, choose `*.asc` as file format, click `Save`.

Answer (score 1):

You would also like to give light on the 'Data history' option present in the File-> Options->Measurement-> Data history. If data history is set to 'none' then a your log file will not contain all the information if your trace is of larger size. Try changing data history option to 4Gb or 200Gb.